# mongodb php Data reference and update

Tags: php, mongodb, mongodb-query, data-modeling, database

hi i need help with mongodb and PHP data strucrue and refrence
i have 4 colletion

```
CARS
PLANES
LOGS
BUYS
```

in CARS/PLANES i have a doucments like this:

```
{_id :  ObjectId("57ce7c49c2c13f6818000029")
,userid: 12345,
time: timestemp,
buys: 5,
type: car,
score : 9
}
```

each time i add new car/plane to the collection i need to add a doucment to the LOGS collection with the objectid of the orginal doucment.
so when i do a search on logs by id i wil get id refrance for the doucment

```
$logs->findOne(array('_id' => $objid ));
```

and then when a user buy item i update the orginal doucment in CARS i do the same on LOGS for $inc buy 1

```
$logs->findAndModify(array("_id" => $objid ),
 array('$inc' => array('buy' => 1 ))

$cars->findAndModify(array("_id" => $objid ),
 array('$inc' => array('buy' => 1 ))
```

after i have done this i add new document on BUYS collection and a new document on LOGS collection for id refenrce to the notifaction

but now my boss need me to add a share feature so a user can "share" the car or plane and it wil show up on user frinds notification so i just add a new doucments on LOGS and changed the id and date of the user so i wil get it on search.

the problom is that i need to display the "buys" count from the orginal doucments on the logs serach

i can just add new document on LOGS each time a user 'share' and modify all 'share' logs when a user buys new item , but i dont think its a smart idea to update 10000 document for me to get the 'live' count of buys form the orgial document

i have read about mongodb ref but i didnt understand how its work 
can someone help me?
thanks

Comment: MongoDB ref no longer exists in the database past 3 as such it is useless

Comment: thanks, so waht can i do?